# how randomly select from string then concatenate?

Tags: r

how to randomly select 3 words from the vector and then concatenate them separated by single space:

```
x <-  c("jhonny","devin","Sara","david","Dan")
slt <- sample(x,3,replace = TRUE)
str_to_title(slt)
str_c(slt,sep = " ")

> x <-  c("jhonny","devin","Sara","david","Dan")
> slt <- sample(x,3,replace = TRUE)
> str_to_title(slt)
[1] "David" "Devin" "David"
> str_c(slt,sep = " ")
[1] "david" "devin" "david"
```

looking for "david devin david"

Comment: If you want one string as output, use `stringr::str_c(slt, collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `paste()` with `collapse = " "` to create a single string that has three randomly selected names from `x` (where `x` is the data from your question):

```
slt <- paste(sample(x, 3, replace = TRUE), collapse = " ")
```

Output:

```
#[1] "Dan Sara devin"
```

Comment: there is no other way?? without collapse = " "

Comment: I dont know off the top of my head but there are much smarter coders than me on here that may be able to help.

Comment: @david what's wrong with `collapse`? It's possible without (`do.call(paste, as.list(slt))` for example), but paste with collapse is pretty standard.

Comment: This will also work `paste(slt[1], slt[2], slt[3])`, but it gets tedious with more than 3 names.

Comment: @david I'm also curious to know what the issue is with `collapse = " "`. This is *exactly* what `paste` with `collapse` is for (like so many R functions, `paste` is vectorised). If this too much typing, roll it up into a custom function, e.g.: `str_join <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "); str_join(slt)`.

Comment: nothing wrong with collapse= " ", I just to learn all the ways we can do it.